# Passing Parameters / setting State from Stacknavigator Header-Button Action to current View in react-native

Tags: react-native, parameters, react-navigation

i am wondering, if it is possible to have a header-button action within a stack-navigator header to manipulate currents view parameters / states.

What i want to achieve is a button, which will set a flag, so the view can react with it ( most likely an icon of a pen or so, when clicking it will set the "edit-mode" flag so the view can change to a state where the user can modify the list shown in the view e.g. Netflix download List on a mobile device ).

I have read, that a view can access navigation.state.params. But how can i set them, since i want to pass them to the current view and do not want to navigate to another screen.

here is the navigator:

```
const DownloadsStackNavigator = StackNavigator({
Main: {
    screen: Downloads,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: "Downloads",
        tabBarLabel: 'Downloads',
        headerLeft: (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen")}
                style={styles.headerLeftButton}>
                <Icon name="bars" size={18} color={STYLES.HIGHLIGHT_COLOR} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
        headerRight: (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {

                    /* NOT WORKING 
                    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
                        navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.setParams({
                            params: { reload: true, mode: "edit" },
                            mode: "List"
                        }))
                    });

                    navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.setParams({
                        params: { reload: true, mode: "edit" },
                        key: "List"
                    }));

                     */

                    // MAGIC SHOULD HAPPEN HERE
                }}
                style={styles.headerLeftButton}>
                <Icon name="cog" size={18} color={STYLES.HIGHLIGHT_COLOR} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
        headerStyle: COMPONENT_STYLES.headerStyle,
        headerBackTitle: "Menu",
        headerTintColor: STYLES.HIGHLIGHT_COLOR,
        headerTitleStyle: { color: STYLES.TEXT_COLOR_INVERTED },
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name="search" size={STYLES.ICON_FONT_SIZE} color={tintColor} />)

    })
}})
```

Do you have any hints for me? Thanks a lot!

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

```
headerRight: (
    <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
            navigation.setParams({
                reload: true,
                mode: "edit"
            });
        }}
        style={styles.headerLeftButton}
    >
        <Icon name="cog" size={18} color={STYLES.HIGHLIGHT_COLOR} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
),
```

Comment: Thx for your reply! 
How would i access this in the view? 

I tried accessing  **this.props.navigation.state.params**, but the return value is always undefined. and i can see that the Stacknavigator is having a navigation.state.params object, but the view doesnt. i guess the view does not rerender. can i force it somehow?

Comment: After press on headerRight Downloads screen should have **this.props.navigation.state.params**.

Comment: Perfect! i had to avoid errors with this function to have it not throwing errors:

isInEditMode() {
  if (
   this.props.navigation &&
   this.props.navigation.state &&
   this.props.navigation.state.params &&
   this.props.navigation.state.params.showEditMode !== null
  ) {
   return this.props.navigation.state.params.showEditMode;
  }

  return false;
 }